# UIWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest only called once?

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview

In my iPhone app, I have a UIWebView where I'm loading a local html. Everything works up just fine, but now I want to be able to handle local links (to footnotes): when I click on a local link, I want to be able to jump to the footnote refered by it, then be able to come back.

```
<a href="#tofootnote">jump to footnote</a>
```

I handled this by adding my code to shouldStartLoadWithRequest and intercepting local link clicks; when a local link is clicked, I work my magic (hide some ui elements, add a back button, etc..); clicking on the back button jumps me back to the original location in the html document.

The problem is that clicking ONCE AGAIN on the link no longer calls shouldStartLoadWithRequest. I.e., the following code:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
 NSLog(@"foo bar");
 return YES;
}
```

only displays "foo bar" ONCE (actually, twice - the first time when I'm initially loading the document), but only ONCE afterwards, regardless of how many times I'm clicking on the local link

So, unless anyone has a better explanation, I'm guessing that the UIWebView caches the doc or link or something and no longer calls the handler after the initial call; If this is the case, how can I clear this internal cache up? (without reloading the document)

Comment: PS. I'm loading the UIWebView using loadHTMLString (because I need to set up the baseURL), so I can't set up the Cache Policy for the original loading request.

Comment: Actually, even using urlrequest and cache policy still doesn't work. Help me, please!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only solution I've found for this problem is to string-replace all the anchors from 
"#anchor" to something that is considered a URL, like "|anchor". This way UIWebView will think it's a real link and attempt the request when clicked. This solution obviously will only work if you are handling all the clicks yourself and hence can interpret the changed anchors. I can understand the reason for the behavior of UIWebView, but it is rather frustrating. The delegate really needs messages to match the onclick, etc. handlers.

Comment: You say you can understand the reason. Can you explain? I can't understand the reason at all and as far as I'm concerned this is a bug in UIWebView. Whether the delegate is called or not, the webview should navigate to the specified link any time it is clicked, not only once.

Comment: The reason is simple.. Technically the UIWebView callbacks that currently exist are for handling the "retrieval" of the clicked web pages. When you do a click on a hash link you aren't retrieving a page, only navigating in the current page. Hence technically it's not a bug. Unless you consider bad API design to be a bug. I tend to think bad design is a bug.. but I concede Apple might have a different opinion ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I'm able to workaround this by setting `window.location` to a dummy anchor after handling the valid one.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)aWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ([[request URL] fragment]) {
        if ([[[request URL] fragment] isEqualToString:@"__DUMMY_ANCHOR"])
            return NO;

        // Do your custom handling of the anchor here

        // Change the location to a non-existent anchor
        [aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location='#__DUMMY_ANCHOR'"];

        return NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One trick I found when I ran into this issue using jquery mobile embedded page changes was to add a random number onto the hash.  This way iOS seems to think it's a new request:

```
//set location hash to path
set: function( path ) {
    path += "&" + Math.random();
    location.hash = path;
},
```

This should work by dynamically setting the path through an onclick event as well.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be happening for me too when I use an onclick="window.location.hash = ...; return false;" instead of capturing the click.

If I scroll around a little bit or click on another anchor, I can use the link again.

Answer (score 0):

If your are loading the content using the loadHTMLString, like:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
```

Then it seem to be sufficient just to reload the html-string. Clicking the anchor will then (again) call your delegate hook.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on Ben Dolman's (working) code above. It "resets" the UIWebView cache with the two dummy links so that subsequent links will still call the method. First it saves the internal link, or fragment in an NSString called savedFragment. It then tells the UIWebview to load the first dummy link #pageX and then another #pageY. Finally it grabs the savedFragment and uses it to construct the page number, which is then used in a seperate method to scroll the UIWebview to the correct location.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {


   if ([[request URL] fragment]) { //check if fragment exists (treat as internal link)

       NSString *fragment = [[request URL] fragment];

       //If the fragment is neither "pageX" nor "pageY", treat as an internal link in the PDF
       if (![fragment isEqualToString:@"pageX"] &&
           ![fragment isEqualToString:@"pageY"]) {

           savedFragment = fragment; //hold the fragment in savedFragment (NSString)
           [pdfWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location='#pageX'"]; //load UIWebView with first dummy link

       } else if ([fragment isEqualToString:@"pageX"]) {

           [pdfWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location='#pageY'"]; //load UIWebView with second dummy link

       } else {

           NSString *pageString = [savedFragment stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"page" withString:@""]; //grab the page from savedFragment
           int page = [pageString intValue];
           [self scrollWebViewToPage:page-1]; //scroll to page (seperate method)
       }

       return NO; //do not load any of the dummy links

   } else {

       return YES; //first load of PDF into UIWebView should be allowed
   }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try 'touch'ing the anchor tag (assign it to itself). My hypothesis is that will cause the DOM to update, making it check the link again. Haven't tested this, it's just an idea!

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem at the moment.. I tried your solution, and it doesn't help.

Answer (score -1):

NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL cachePolocy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];

[webView loadRequest:request];

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem at the moment.. And I attest that changing the cache policy option doesn't work.