# UIWebview shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate method gets called only once (inconsistent)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm loading a local html template with some js code into webview. It works most of the time. But sometimes, the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` delegate gets called once and won't get called at all later. By the way, I'm seeing this issue more consistently in iOS 9.1 and above.

Whenever this issue occurs, if I recreate the webview and load same content, then it works fine. So, I wanted to know why it doesn't work the first time (inconsistent) but works the second time.

I'm calling

```
[_webView setDelegate:nil]; 
//and 
[_webView stopLoading]; in dealloc method.
```

Would be helpful if anyone can suggest something.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/q/17627838/767329

Comment: @Avijit Adding "thanks" is the opposite of what an edit should do. You're actually encouraged to *remove* thanks from posts, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 0):

I think somewhere your webView just loses its delegate. So it may just reset it with other one somewhere in code or just seed with nil. Looking to your posted code I can predict such situation - two instances has references to this webView. One instance should delete and it's calling dealloc method - webView delegate sets to nil, but other instance still using this same webView, but now it has delegate nil. As delegate is nil than webView won't send any message to him. It's only my prediction, still you'd should check if your delegate is nil or not and than begin new problem research. Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've checked the delegate and is not getting set to nil anywhere during js execution. Also, i'm using only one instance at a time. Every time, a new webview instance is created for execution..

Comment: You can also simply check it by adding any output string to shouldStartLoadWithRequest method  - if anything will be outputted to console than delegate responds correctly and you just have non responding instance right now(instance that responds may be somewhere else or even loses reference)